# Echo something inside loop using variable concatenization

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

How can I echo `active` in position of `$HERE` when `if($i++ == 0)` ?

```
  $i = 0;
  foreach ( $images as $img) {

    $carousel .= '
    <div class="item $HERE">
      ...
    </div>
    ';

  }
```

Comment: from where the `$HERE` comes or calculated?

Comment: Try this :->>>   $carousel .= '<div class="item '.($i++ == 0)?'active' : ''.' ">... </div>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the variable `$HERE`  as shown below:

```
  $i = 0;
  foreach ( $images as $img) {
    if($i++ == 0){
        $HERE = "active";
    }
    else{
        $HERE = "";
    }
    $carousel .= '
    <div class="item '.$HERE.'">
      ...
    </div>
    ';

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
  foreach ( $images as $img) {
 $HERE = ($i++ == 0 ? 'active':'');
    $carousel .= '
    <div class="item '.$HERE.'">
      ...
    </div>
    ';

  }
```